# How to Style the legend color boxes as lines for Line, Bar and Pie charts in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I have been trying to search for a solution to get the **legend colorboxes as line using chartjs**, but it looks like we can only reduce them to vertical boxes using boxWidth parameter but not horizontal due to the absence of boxLength parameter. *I cannot tweak the chartjs library as the production environment downloads it on the go*.

I have used the pointStyle as line to get it for the linechart alone, but I cannot find a way to get the same for barcharts and pie charts

here is the code I have used for linechart

```
legend: {
                onClick: this.onLegendCallBack,
                display: true,
                position : 'bottom',
                labels: {
                    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                    fontSize: 12,
                    boxWidth : 1,
                    usePointStyle: true
                }
            }
```

Comment: The best way you can do this is by using a html legend ( https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends ), in the new beta you will also be able to use pointstyle for bar charts by default but not any other charts

Comment: Thanks for your comment [LeeLenalee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682983/leelenalee) , So technically we cannot construct a line bar for legend with the inbuilt configuration for all type of charts